# Сортировка и вывод товаров из mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Есть простой код :

```
     <select>
     <option>марка авто</option>
     </select>
     <select>
     <option>модель авто</option>
      </select>
     <button>подобрать запчасть</button>
```

Нужно реализовать фильтр по 2ум категориям "Марка авто" и "Модель авто" ,
 при клике по опции "Марка авто" должен раскрывался соответственно список марок авто(Toyota,Honda,Mazda и т.п), далее при выборе марки подгружались уже модели для конкретной выбранной марки, после выбора опций фильтра пользователь нажимает кнопку "подобрать запчасть" и его должно перебросить на страницу с подобранными товарами.Надеюсь все понятно объяснил, заранее огромное спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Этот код простой потому что это не тот код, который получится в итоге

Comment: И это фильтрация, а не сортировка

Comment: Без разницы, хотелось бы услышать как это реализовать

Comment: Создавайте запросы и получайте возврат. Это всё, что хотелось бы сказать на такие "вопросы"

Comment: Если не знаете как это реализовать то зачем писать вообще комментарий?Я спросил знающих людей которые смогут объяснить алгоритм действий как реализовать вот такой фильтр подбора товаров....А у вас ответ а ля сядь за комп-напиши код.

Answer (score 2):

При событии select отсылайте запрос на сервер (ajax), передавая параметры (марку, модель и тд и тп), на их основе формируйте sql строку (добавляйте условие в конструкцию where) и делайте запрос в бд, получая нужную вам информацию и передавая ее в ответ. Используйте библиотеку jquery.

Comment: а можно пример кода?

Comment: Ему плевать, на устройство, он просто хочет, чтобы за него написали

Comment: @goodmice это уже полноценный модуль,а не учебный материал, за это мани берут)

Comment: Мани не вопрос;) Напиши модуль рабочий я заплачу!

Comment: @SanychGoilo да ладно, пусть люди думают, что я богатый) А он пусть этим кодом и подавится :P

Comment: @ilyaaa521 вам уже привели пример кода (хотя и не полного), этого не достаточно? Если сами не справитесь, то за вознаграждение могу помочь,пишите на указанную почту в профиле.

Comment: @SanychGoilo когда нашёл работу на stack overflow)

Comment: @goodmice сейчас все в отпусках, на работе тишина)

Comment: @SanychGoilo это да) Но всегда есть фриланс)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<form action="get.php" method="GET">
    <select name="mark">
        <option value="название категории"></option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select name="model">
        <option value="название категории"></option>
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Подобрать">
</form>
```

PHP (get.php):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['mark']) || !isset($_GET['model']))
    exit();
$mark = strip_tags($_GET['mark']);
$model = strip_tags($_GET['model']);


$db = mysqli("host", "login", "pass");
$db->select_db("db_name");
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE mark=$mark AND model=$model");
while($line = $result->fetch_assocc()){
    //Вывод об
}
?>
```

Либо через AJAX дописать:

```
$('form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/get.php?mark'=$(this).find('[name="mark"]').val()+
             '&model'=$(this).find('[name="model"]').val(),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            //Подгрузка на страницу из data
        },
        error: function(err){
            //Обработка ошибок
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```js
 $("select#carBrand").change(function(){ 
      $.post("main/getModel/",{brandId: $("select#carBrand").val()}, function(result){
            var json=jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if(json.data){
                var carModelList="";
                $.each(json.data, function(k,v){
                    carModelList+="<option value='"+v.id+"'>"+v.name+"</option>";
                });
                $("select#carModel").children('option').remove();
                $("select#carModel").append(carModelList);

            
           }
           });

         });
```

HTML:

```
<select id="carBrand">
<option>Audi</option>
<option>BMW</option>
<option>Toyota</option>
</select>
<select id="carModel">
</select>
```

PHP:

```
return $db->query("SELECT * FROM carModels WHERE brand_id=".$_POST['brandId']);
```